# Not able to add xtype grid to div in EXtjs

Tags: extjs, extjs6, dataview, extjs-grid, xtemplate

I am trying add form panel in dataView, i have ItemTPL where i have written divs and in that div I want to call Extjs Form Panel, But when i can call extjs form panel i get below error
"[W] XTemplate evaluation exception: Cannot read property 'dom' of null"

```js
getGrid: function () {
                Ext.onReady(function(){

                    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                        title: 'Support Ticket Request',
                        width: 650,
                        height: 500,
                        renderTo: 'myForm',
                        style: 'margin: 50px',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            items: [{
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'First Name', 
                                name: 'FirstName',
                                labelAlign: 'top',
                                cls: 'field-margin',
                                flex: 1
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Last Name',  
                                name: 'LastName',
                                labelAlign: 'top',
                                cls: 'field-margin',
                                flex: 1
                            }]
                        }]
                    });

                });
                
                
                return '<div id="myForm"></div>';

                //return '<img src="resources/images/img2.jpg" class="shared-img" alt="Smiley face">';
            },
```

```html
'<div class="contents-wrap">' +
                        '<div class="shared-by"><a href="#">{name}</a> shared an image</div>' +
                        '{[this.getGrid()]}' +
                    '</div>'
```

Comment: There is a component data view: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/modern/Ext.dataview.Component.html   THis allows you to create a panel with a grid, or whatever you want in each dataview item.

Comment: @mcg1103 - Thank for you reply...I need some kind of example
Can you help me with this Sencha fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jfa
Is there something wrong with this fiddle?
My requirement is something like below :
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#profile

In this i want to implement timeline and want to remove Image from timeline and add Grid data into that

Comment: The fiddle is now coming up.  Just add to remove renderTo and set to fullscreen: true. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/39n7

Comment: @mcg1103 - Thank you so much. But my requirement is not fulfilled as i can't call this inside div. Div is needed because i want a timeline structure...Which can be seen here:
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#profile

Comment: So you want a grid to be one node of the timeline.   I still say  you should be using component data view.  You would create a container that is like a single node of the timeline.  Then it would be easy to put the grid.. or whatever in the left portion of the time line node.   If you wanted to do what you are trying to do you would have to render the grid in that div.  Look at the renderTo config of panel.